# Ubuntu precise amd64 packages missing for ROS Fuerte

Tags: ros, installation, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use Ubuntu 12.04 precise for amd64 architecture.
After some modifications to my system today I had to remove ROS Fuerte and reinstall it. The main problem I face is that I find no amd64 packages of ROS when I update my package cache but only i386 instead. Looking to the repository under dists/precise/main I have seen that there are no entries regarding ros-fuerte in the Packages file under binary-amd64 directory (which is not the case for Packages file under binary-i386). Moreover, I noticed that the files have been updated yesterday.
I am curious if someone else has tried to install Fuerte on an amd64 based Precise system today, and if they have faced a similar issue. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50881/ubuntu-precise-amd64-packages-missing-for-ros-fuerte/) by [mdouskos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3824/mdouskos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-12-20

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2012-12-20**:
Same issue here. I would expect the mailing list to have more info soon and a fix to be out quickly based on past experience.

**Comment by [Kyle Strabala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1173/kyle-strabala/) on 2012-12-20**:
I am having the same problem.

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2012-12-20**:
I was about to post that question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems to be back up now.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2012-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1